# Errror when trying to set the text of a ComboBox control

Tags: oracle, listview, vb6, combobox

This is my code that tries to set the text of a ComboBox when I click an item in a ListView.

```
Private Sub ListView1_Click()
  If ListView1.ListItems.Count > 0 Then
    Text1.Text = ListView1.ListItems(ListView1.SelectedItem.Index).Text
    Text2.Text = ListView1.ListItems(ListView1.SelectedItem.Index).ListSubItems(1).Text

    Sql = "SELECT A.AID,B.LOC_NAME,C.SNAME FROM ASSET A,LOCATION B,SUPPLIER C WHERE "
    Sql = Sql + "A.LOC_ID=B.LOC_ID AND A.SUP_ID=C.SUP_ID AND AID=" & Text1.Text
    RS.Open Sql, CON, 1, 2

    COM1
    Combo1.Text = RS!LOC_NAME                       //combo with style - 2
    COM5
    Combo5.Text = RS!SNAME                          //combo with style - 2
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub COM5()
   If Combo5.ListIndex = -1 Then
     For I = 0 To Combo5.ListCount - 1
       Combo5.ListIndex = I
     Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub COM1()
 If Combo1.ListIndex = -1 Then
   For I = 0 To Combo1.ListCount - 1
      Combo1.ListIndex = I
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

However, when I click on the ListView1, I get this error:

> 'text' property is read only

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: try debugging your code! is it a problem with ListView1, or a problem with your record set?

Comment: IF I RUN THIS SQL STMT IN ORACLE(BACKEND) THEN IT GIVES CORRECT RESULTS BUT IN FRONTEND GIVES ERROR........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a combobox with the *dropdown list* style you can only select an item with `.text` if that item already exists, so `combo1.text = "xxx"` errors if `"xxx"` is not present in the list.

To select *or* add based on existence you can;

```
Private Sub SelectOrAddToCombo(combo As ComboBox, value As String)
    Dim i As Long
    With combo
        For i = 0 To combo.ListCount - 1
            If StrComp(.List(i), value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                combo.ListIndex = i
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        .AddItem value
        .ListIndex = .NewIndex
    End With
End Sub

...

SelectOrAddToCombo Combo1, RS!LOC_NAME
SelectOrAddToCombo Combo5, RS!SNAME
```

It's not clear what the point of your `COM5()`/`COM1()` routines are.

For the listview, rather than click look at the

`ListView1_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)`

event which passes you the clicked item negating the need for `ListView1.SelectedItem` (which can cause errors if its `Nothing`).

Comment: <ListView1_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)>        i M NOT HAVING THIS EVEVT IN LIST............... COM1()/5() SHOWS IF U DOESN'T WANNA SELECT ITEM FROM READONLY COMBOS THEN THEY'LL RELAY AS IT IS..........

Answer (score 0):

yes, you must populate the combobox with the array(using additem value) before set the .text propierty, if the text that you want to set on the combobox does not exits in the array you get this error